# WebService para app android sem usar tomcat

Tags: android, web-service, android-studio

gostaria de sabe alguma alternativa para o tomcat, para eu fazer um web service para meu aplicativo android, onde eu tenho meu banco de dados local quero sincronizar essas informações através do webservice.
Se tiverem algum material ensinando a montar o webservice, agradeço desde já.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Poderia utilizar jboss, wildfly, glassfish.

Recomendo também a plataforma Firebase, onde rapidamente cria um banco de dados nosql na nuvem.

Curso : https://br.udacity.com/course/firebase-essentials-for-android--ud009/

Não fiz esse especificamente, mas costumas ser muito bons.